# Apollo GraphQL error thrown with custom GQL scalar type containing regex .test()

Tags: regex, typescript, graphql, apollo

I'm creating a GraphQL custom scalar in TypeScript and building out the serialize/parseValue/parseLiteral functions.  I'd like my scalar to match incoming values against a regex, but when I include `if (value.test(yearMonthDayRegex)) {}` as a condition, I get an Apollo runtime error:

```
TypeError: value.test is not a function
            at GraphQLScalarType.coerceType (/Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/packages/core/src/lib/gqlScalarTypes.ts:30:20)
            at coerceInputValueImpl (/Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/node_modules/.pnpm/graphql@16.6.0/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:151:26)
            at coerceInputValueImpl (/Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/node_modules/.pnpm/graphql@16.6.0/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:117:34)
            at coerceInputValueImpl (/Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/node_modules/.pnpm/graphql@16.6.0/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:117:34)
            at coerceInputValue (/Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/node_modules/.pnpm/graphql@16.6.0/node_modules/graphql/utilities/coerceInputValue.js:32:10)
            at coerceVariableValues (/Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/node_modules/.pnpm/graphql@16.6.0/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:132:69)
            at getVariableValues (/Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/node_modules/.pnpm/graphql@16.6.0/node_modules/graphql/execution/values.js:45:21)
            at buildExecutionContext (/Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/node_modules/.pnpm/graphql@16.6.0/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:280:63)
            at execute (/Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/node_modules/.pnpm/graphql@16.6.0/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:116:22)
            at /Users/mej/Documents/elastigraph/elastigraph/node_modules/.pnpm/@envelop+core@3.0.6/node_modules/@envelop/core/cjs/orchestrator.js:376:33
```

Is there a way to incorporate regex functionality into this custom scalar?  Or am I missing something more basic about regex in TS?  My regex looks like `const yearMonthDayRegex = /^d{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;`.

Comment: I've verified that the type of `value` is string.

Comment: You probably mean `yearMonthDayRegex.test(value)`. `String#test()` is not a thing, but [`RegExp#test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is. Alternatively, you can use [`String#match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), which returns a match array (always truthy) or `null` (falsy) if no match is found; this is less performant than `.test()`, however.

Answer (score 0):

@InSync's comment is correct.  Regexes are tested with regex.test("teststring") rather than teststring.test(regex).